# "Send Document Set to Repository" not appearing in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, document-set

I am trying to create a workflow to move a document set to another library based on metadata using a 2010 workflow. This works great in 2013 on-premise, but the "Send Document Set to Repository" workflow action simply does not appear in SharePoint Online. I have set up the content organizer on the site, I even set up a records center, though that was not required in 2013. I've found no helpful documentation on this issue. In the below screenshot, the outlined workflow action simply does not appear in workflows on SharePoint Online sites. Thanks!

[image: SharePoint 2010 workflow]